# Linux Mint 1404 HWE End of Life

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 using Kernel 4.4.0-64-generic and get the following message during login.

```
WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack 
ended on 2016-08-04:



* http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial

and reboot your system.
```

Unfortunately, `sudo do-release-upgrade` only tells me that nothing is found and the `apt-get` command exits with

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386 (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-lts-xenial : Conflicts: libegl1-mesa (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgles2-mesa (>= 0~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: You are using Linux Mint, why are you trying to do an Ubuntu upgrade? You should look at www.linuxmint.com for proper upgrade instructions. Although Mint is based on Ubuntu, it is NOT the same and if you continue down the path of trying to upgrade it like Ubuntu you will likely wind up having to reinstall from scratch.

Comment: Nevertheless, the problem remains - and it is not a Mint specific issue but is due to ubuntu packages. Any advice?

Comment: yes... Do the Mint upgrade to 18... The steps are clearly defined. http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3068

Comment: Well that was easy.

Comment: I take it that worked? Should I add it as an answer so it can be properly accepted and the question marked as answered?

Comment: Sure. I've seen some threads with similar problems but suggesting different solutions that have not worked out. Seems reasonable to provide the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that Linux Mint 17, 17.1, 17.2 and 17.3 will be supported until 2019. I am not sure why you are getting that message which is specific to the Hardware Enablement Stack (using newer kernels and libraries to add compatibility to long term suupport releases). Although 17.X is supported for the long term, it is best in most cases to upgrade and maintain the upgrade path.

Be aware that 3.16/3.19 kernels used in LM17 are vastly different than the 4.4+ kernels used in LM18 releases. This is not a problem a for most users but should be researched as there is some incompatibility for certain hardware and software applications.

The issue here is that you are using Linux Mint, not Ubuntu, and although Mint is based on Ubuntu... the upgrade process is drastically different and specific to Mint.

General upgrade information is [here](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3068). Detailed instructions from Linux Mint are available [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2316). Be sure to read the [release notes](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah.php) prior to upgrading. I would also recommend testing your computer by booting the latest version via USB prior to continuing.

Although the chances of something going completely wrong are small, it is a possibility, and you should backup all your personal and important data that you may need prior to starting.

Open a terminal window and set the scroll back to unlimited.

1. Change to the sudo shell with `sudo -i`
2. Start by updating the apt cache so it is current with `apt update`
3. Update all packages with `apt upgrade`
4. Install the Mint upgrade tool with `apt install mintupgrade`
5. Check the upgrade environment with `mintupgrade check`. This a simulation, your system is not being changed or modified, and it will tell you if you can most likely upgrade successfully. **It is extremely important that you pay close attention to the output of this command.** If it shows packages which are preventing the upgrade, remove them (and take note of them so you can try to reinstall them after the upgrade). Keep using "mintupgrade check" and do not proceed to the next step, until you're happy with the output.
6. Download all necessary packages with `mintupgrade download`.  this command doesn't actually perform the upgrade itself, but just downloads the packages. Note also that this command points your system to the Linux Mint 18 repositories (if you want to go back to Linux Mint 17.3 after using this command, you still can, with the command "mintupgrade restore-sources"). Use the "mintupgrade download" command until all the packages are successfully downloaded.
7. To apply the upgrades, enter `mintupgrade upgrade` and allow the process to complete. **This step is non-reversible, and once you performed it, you cannot go back.**
8. Reboot your computer.

Upon completing these steps, you should no longer have a HWE error and should be on a current release of Linux Mint. Perform updates normally.

Answer (score 0):

Install the unmet dependencies listed in the apt output. Specifically 'libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial', 'libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386', and remove the conflicts listed there too. Repair apt too, because it says you have broken packages.

Comment: According to `dpkg -l | grep ^..r` there are no broken packages. Will try to install dependencies manually.

Comment: The apt output literally says you have broken packages here....
      E: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Odd.

Comment: I know. That is one of the reasons I am asking.